# Flask test response to post request incorrectly returns 400

Tags: python, post, testing, flask, python-requests

I'm working on unit tests for my Flask app. I have a URL that can be accessed only by an authorized (logged in) user. As a setup I create a test app, a temp database and a test user. I then authorize the test user.

I tested GET request on for this URL and it correctly returns 200 response. However, if I send any test POST or DELETE requests, instead of 200 they return 400 and 401 respectively.
I spell checked all the arguments and I'm pretty sure I'm sending correct test arguments together with the requests, but I still can't figure out what's the problem.

Is there anything different in testing POST and DELETE requests than in GET requests that I don't understand?

Here are my example GET and POST request tests and a corresponding implementation:

Tests:

```
def test_successful_get(self):
    self.login('valid_user', 'valid_password')
    response = self.app.get('/home', data=dict(parameter='parameter'))
    assert_that(response.status_code, equal_to(200))


def test_successful_post(self):
    self.login('valid_user', 'valid_password')
    response = self.app.post('/home', data=dict(parameter='parameter'))
    assert_that(response.status_code, equal_to(200))
```

Implementation:

```
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
@login_required
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        insert_param_in_db(request.form['parameter'])
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        remove_param_from_db(request.form['parameter'])
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```